# ASP.NET MVC Data Annotations Persisting Between Layers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am learning MVC, and in trying to separate my business layer I cannot get Data Annotations to persist between them.  For Instance I would like the Name of a Column to persist throughout my application, so I have created a partial class to buddy up with my Persistence model, and a View Model to go with my View.  However the View does not display the Display Name from the Partial Class.  I have simplified my code to just show one property.

Persistence Model

```
public partial class tblPart
{
  public string Description1 { get; set; }
}
```

Buddy Model

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Metadata))]
public partial class tblPart
{
    private class Metadata
    {
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string Description1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View Model

```
public class CreateQuotesPartsViewModel
{
    public string Description1 { get; set; }
}
```

View

`@Html.DisplayFor(a => CreateQuotesPartsViewModel.Description1)`

And my column name is "Description1" when I want it to be Description.  I am aware I can place the Annotation on the View Model, and if I do put it there, it displays properly.  How can I make the annotation stay when placed in my domain layer?

Comment: Short answer is you can't. But a `[Display]` attribute is a view specific attribute and belongs in a view model, not a data model. And since you are using a view model, why are you using a partial anyway?

Comment: I'm using the partial because it's not a code first database, but still want to use migrations.